# Combinatorial Marble Choosing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag contains $3$ red marbles, $3$ green ones, $1$ lavender one, $6$ yellows, and $4$ orange marbles.

How many sets of five marbles include either the lavender one or exactly one yellow one but not both colors?

I am getting $990$ as an answer but that is incorrect. Please help

Comment: How are you getting 990?  If you show your working then the error could be pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

> A bag contains 3 red marbles, 3 green ones, 1 lavender one, 6 yellows, and 4 orange marbles.
>
> How many sets of five marbles include either the lavender one or exactly one yellow one but not both colors?

It *depends* on whether you can tell the difference between marbles of the same color.

**Assuming the marbles of the same color are indistinguishable:**

The set is built by selecting either 1 lavender or 1 yellow (2 choices), and then 4 other marbles chosen from the 3 red, 3 green, and 4 orange marbles.  The four others can be selected by:

1. Choosing a quadruple: ${1 \choose 1} = 1$ choice (all orange)
2. Choosing a tripple and a single: ${3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}= 6$ choices.
3. Choosing a double and two singles: ${3 \choose 1}{2\choose 2} =3$ choices.
4. Or choosing two doubles: ${3 \choose 2}=3$ choices

$$2\times(1+6+3+3) = 26\text{ distinct sets}$$

---

**However, if marbles of the same color are distinguishable:**

The set is built by selecting either the 1 lavender or 1 of the 6 yellow, and the 4 other marbles are chosen from the remaining 10:

$$\left(1+{6\choose 1}\right)\times{10\choose 4}= 1470 \text{ distinct sets}$$